# Is there a way to list the supported networks from Temple using Taquito?

Tags: smart-contracts, taquito, thanos

I'm using Taquito with Temple wallet (prev. Thanos) i my dapp.

To connect the wallet I need to do `wallet.connect(<name_of_network>)`.
If I'm using the wrong network name here I get an error from the wallet.

Is there a way to list the available networks (names) in Temple using Taquito?

Comment: Are you using the `@temple-wallet/dapp` package or the `@taquito/beacon-wallet` package?

Answer (score 1):

`wallet.connect` seems to indicate you are using the `@temple-wallet/dapp` package. If you are using TypeScript, there is the [`TempleDAppNetwork` enum](https://github.com/madfish-solutions/templewallet-dapp/blob/master/src/types.ts#L115) that you can import from the package with all the different network names. With the right settings on your editor, you should get a list of the network names when you type the parameter of `wallet.connect` :)

Comment: I am using the @temple-wallet/dapp package yes  And I have found the enum. However, what threw me a curveball was the recent `edonet` -> `edo2net` renaming. If I try and pass `edonet` it throws "Some of the parameters you provided are invalid". If I pass `edo2net` it works. And none of those are in the enum ‍♂️

Comment: `edo2net` is definitely in the enum (check the link in my answer, it's even twice ).

Comment: Yeah I was on an older version  That too makes the point that it would be better to query the Template plugin for it's supported versions ✌️